# Finding an expression relating two congruence moduli

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose I have a positive integer $a$ which can be written as $\equiv n (mod) t$ for some $n$ and $t$. Now if I have another integer $b$ related to $a$ as: $b=\sqrt{(2t+1)a^2+t^2}$, and I can write $b \equiv o (mod) t$; then does there exist a simple relation between $n$ and $o$? If yes, how can I proceed to find it? More specifically, given $n$ and $t$, can $o$ be found? The question arises since I do not want to deal with potentially very large squares if $b$ is large.

For example, I can write $a=160$ as $\equiv 10(mod)30$. $b$ is then $1250$ which can be written as $\equiv 20(mod)30$. The question is to have a simple relation between $n=10$ and $o=20$.

Comment: By reducing $b^2=(2t+1)a^2+t^2$ modulo $t$ we get $n^2\equiv o^2\pmod t$.